# HasRole class no definda

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7, laravel-8

Tengo el siguiente controlador en Laravel pero me aparece el siguiente error class hasRole no definida:

[image: error hasrole class]

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class DashboardController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
   if(Auth::user()->hasRole('user')){
        return view('userdash');
   }elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole('blogwriter')){
        return view('blogwriterdash');
   }elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
    return view('dashboard');
}
}

public function myprofile()
{
 return view('myprofile');
}

public function postcreate()
{
 return view('postcreate');
}
}
```

Estoy utilizando laraberl Breeze y laratrust, pero no entiendo a que se refiere el error cambie por hasAnyRole pero no se soluciona

Comment: Agrega por favor el mensaje de error tal cual aparece

Comment: edite la descripción y agregue una imagen

Comment: ¿Al usar los métodos te funciona todo? A veces el phpintelephense de vscode no logra encontrar todas las clases asociadas a los archivos dentro del vendor y saltan errores pero que no lo son como tal.

Comment: Ahi no dice que una clase no esta definida, dice que un método llamado `hasRole` no esta definido

Comment: ¿Cómo compruebo si funciona o no?

Answer (score 1):

debes añadir el trait que da el desarrollador del paquete en el modelo user asi

```
  <?php

use Laratrust\Traits\LaratrustUserTrait; // importar el namespace

class User extends Model
{
    use LaratrustUserTrait; // debes agregar esta línea 

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta pero ya tengo todo eso en el model user.php

Comment: tienes error en el ide o en tiempo de ejecución?

Comment: Al ejecutar todo funciona pero las redireciones que tengo no funcionan, teng tres usuarios admin, blogwriter y user, cada uno tiene una vista diferente al momento de hacer login, cada uno con diferentes permisos, pero cual sea que haga login se muestra la vista de user y no de admin menos la de blogerwriter

Comment: si haces un dd que boolean te devueleve el medoto? dd(Auth::user()->hasRole('user'));

Comment: disculpa pero soy nuevo en esto ¿cómo hago un dd?

Comment: asi como te coloque, en el metodo index del controlador coloca asi:  dd(Auth::user()->hasRole('user'));

Comment: Todo funciona el error es la rutas que estaban mal nombradas.